# Lenovo Thinkpad E450 vs Acer V3-371 vs IdeaPad 500s-13

Tags: laptop, linux

I'm helping to buy a computer for a person whose main computer's use will restrain to web browsing, checking e-mail, office tasks but who may occasionally run Windows in a VM or perform some video conversion.

Now I'm left with three offers, all with matte screens and 8GB RAM, sorted by price

- 1700PLN: Lenovo ThinkPad E450, LED 1366x768, i3-5005U, SSD 120G, 8G RAM: [link](http://allegro.pl/laptop-lenovo-thinkpad-e450-i3-5005u-8gb-120ssd-i6494814170.html)
- 1800PLN: the same but with 12G RAM: [link](http://allegro.pl/laptop-lenovo-thinkpad-e450-i3-5005u-12gb-120ssd-i6494814503.html)
- 1950PLN: Acer V3-371, LED 1366x768, i3-5005U, SSD 120G: [link](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/292319-notebook-laptop-133-acer-v3-371-i3-5005u-8gb-120.html)
- 2150PLN: Lenovo IdeaPad 500s-13, LED IPS 1920x1080, i3-6100U, SSD 240G: [link](http://www.x-kom.pl/p/303295-ultrabook-133-lenovo-ideapad-500s-13-i3-6100u-8gb-240-czerwony.html)

I think that 120G of SSD would be plenty for the user. Battery life is very important. Please keep in mind that the earnings in Poland are much lower than in the western countries.

The notebook will run Linux, probably Cinnamon or KDE as its desktop environment.

Are the more expensive options worth the extra cost?

Comment: How much usage is "occasionally"?

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend an i3 CPU for VMs. Maybe if it has VT-d/VT-x/etc (check Intel Ark), but generally I'd say an i3 sounds like a bit too low.

120GB/240GB SSD sounds a bit on the low side for me, but you said the user is fine with it, however, I'd still check.

Battery life, no idea though, sorry.

Comment: @TheBitByte basically, if there's no native Linux program for it and Wine doesn't work. Currently we have one such app, Garmin Express (this is the moment I regret buying a Garmin nav). VM is a last-resort option

Comment: @TheBitByte: i3-5005U latter supports both VT-x and VT-d.

Comment: If you're using VM when wine doesn't work, i.e not serious VM use like I thought, then maybe an i3 is fine. However, 4GB ram sounds a  bit low for running VMs, in my opinion.

Comment: @TheBitByte: All of them have 8GB RAM.

Comment: I googled them and they didn't appear to have 8GB RAM. Could you edit your post to link to the exact models?

Comment: @TheBitByte but the offers are be in Polish. Added the links

Comment: I used google translate, and all three of the laptops look good, in my opinion. One of them had a 14" screen, others had 13", so I'd go with the larger one if it also has VT-x/VT-d support. The specs of all three actually look very similar, the differences I noticed were just Haswell VS Broadwell, and for general use haswell processors are still fine.

Comment: It's Broadwell vs Skylake. The user would rather have a 13.3" than a 14" one if the two were at the same price. (basically it's more about the laptop size than the screen size) But the 13.3" ones are more expensive, so we're wondering if it's worth the extra cost. Besides, is it worth to pay so much for the Skylake processor?

Comment: @TheBitByte: I forgot to add a link for the 4th one, see the edited OP. (Lenovo IdeaPad 500s-13)

Answer (score 1):

Get the cheapest one of those you can that has the smallest screen. They're all going to have about the same battery life otherwise, and they all have enough RAM for the tasks that will be thrown on them if your host OS is a linux distribution.

The more expensive options are not worth the cost.